# three-word compound adjective hyphenation

Tags: phrase-choice, compounds

Which is correct

1. Robotic assisted laparoscopic hysterectomy; or
2. Robotic-assisted laparoscopic hysterectomy.

Similarly also for,

1. Robotic assisted medial and lateral meniscus repair; or
2. Robotic-assisted medial and lateral meniscus repair.

Please explain

Comment: Shouldn't that be either "Robot assisted laparoscopic hysterectomy" or "Robotic laparoscopic hysterectomy"?

Comment: This is what the dictator always dictates.

Comment: I usually do not use the hyphen, but the auditor checking the transcripts always uses the hyphen

Comment: "Robot-assisted" is fine, but not "Robotic-assisted" or "Robotic assisted." The word *robotic* is an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you hyphenate words which function together as an adjective before the noun they are describing. This usually involves joining a noun and an adjective, for example, "*a dog-friendly hotel*". You shouldn't hyphenate words which are already adjectives, for example, "*a charming old hotel*".

In both of your examples, you are describing medical procedures - a laparoscopic hysterectomy, and a lateral meniscus repair.

"Laparoscopic" is an adjective, describing the approach of the procedure, as is the word "lateral" to describe which of the menisci referred to, so there are no need for hyphens there.

"Robotic" and "assisted" are also both adjectives, so these should not be hyphenated. However, "Robotic" is **not** an adjective that describes the entire procedure, so there is a problem. It should be "**robot-assisted**" (assisted by a robot).

However, this may be medical *terminology*, and terminology does not always follow the rules of English grammar. You should follow whatever terminology is being used by the medical professionals.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Ngram variants](https://tinyurl.com/yal2rbcd)

The Ngram seems to favor the hyphens.
 I added the word "robot-assisted", which seems more common in the result than all the others. It appears in regular Google search, too.
It makes more sense to me, since "robotic" is an adjective (though "robotics" is a noun). "Assisted by a robot" works, but "assisted by a robotic" sounds strange.

Comment: The dictator always dictates that way.  I generally do not use the hyphen, but the auditor checking the transcripts always adds one.  Even it is robot-assisted, what does this compound modifier modifies, laparoscopic  or hysterectomy??

Comment: @Clenten What do you mean by your "dictator" reference? Do you feel oppressed by the "auditor"?

Comment: @Clenten The head noun in the noun phrase is "hysterectomy". It is modified by all the adjectives.

Comment: Hi the dictator is the client who i work for, the auditor is one who checks for any grammatical errors in my document before finally sending it to the client.

Comment: I a bit confused, if hysterectomy is the head noun then there should be hyphen between all of the three words i.e. Robotic-assisted-laparoscopic hysterectomy or is it that no matter how many words are in between the compound modifier and the HEAD NOUN, we can still use a hyphen, as I was under the impression that a "hyphen" should only be used in a compound modifier only if it is immediately followed by the noun

Comment: @Clenten You don't generally add hyphens between successive adjectives in a noun phrase. It's just that the word "assisted" may look incomplete by itself. It needs to be preceded by "robot" (or "robotic", as second choice) to mean anything. Then, given "robot assisted", I think the hyphen is optional. But the "dictator" is always right...

Comment: Thank You So Much..Just one doubt..When we hyphenate a compound modifier, example: left-sided pain, the compound modifier "left-sided" is followed immediately by the noun "pain"..if for instance we take this example: left sided neck and back pain; in this case, i prefer not to hyphenate the left sided as it is not immediately followed by the head noun "pain".  Is this correct

Comment: To me, left-sided would be hyphenated, to make clear that it forms a unit. "Left-handed" is a dictionary word. Wikipedia has articles on left- and right-sided heart failure, where "failure" is the head noun, so I think the hyphen should be included.

Comment: Thank you for all your time